# `sh` in Docker behaves buggy (related to i/o)

Tags: docker, terminal

When I try to connect to my docker container (got from https://github.com/gitcoinco/passport-scorer), it outputs weird symbols to console:

```
$ docker exec -t passport-scorer_postgres_1 sh
/ # ^[[45;5R
```

Pressing ENTER does not work as expected for `sh`: it just moves the cursor to beginning of the next line (new `sh` prompt is not produced).

If I type `ls` and press ENTER in this prompt (both directly after this or after first removing `^[[45;5R` by Backspace), the cursor is just moved to the next line (`ls` is not executed).

However, this works as expected:

```
docker exec -t passport-scorer_postgres_1 ls
```

Help to connect to my container.

I use Gnome Terminal.

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Comment: Also reported as a bug: https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/9712

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `-i` flag as well (combined `-it`).

As [Docker official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_exec/) says:

> --interactive -i      Keep STDIN open even if not attached
>
> --tty         -t      Allocate a pseudo-TTY

**Example with detailed comments:**

```bash
# It's not working as you expect because the STDIN is not open (-i)
# so the container doesn't handle the written things from terminal
# (Only the direct command is executed inside the container).
# -------------
>>> docker exec -t 27a4dcfe37df sh
# 
ls

# It's working if I pass directly the "ls" command
# (Because the STDIN is not needed for further operations,
# just run the provided command and that's it).
# -------------
>>> docker exec -t 27a4dcfe37df ls. 
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var

# It's working as you expect.
# The STDIN is kept open (-i) so the user can operate in the terminal
# (inside container). In other words, the container can handle the
# provided details from STDIN.
# -------------
>>> docker exec -it 27a4dcfe37df sh
# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
#
```